# Redux todo list advanced

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm doing a todo list using redux and I want to add sub todo list for each todo, but I can't understand why my line for my reducer is not working (see above) 
Can you help me please ?

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, ADD_SUB_TODO} from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import _ from 'lodash'

const initialState = {
    todos : []
}

export function todo(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case  ADD_TODO:
            return {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text,
                completed: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export function allTodo (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case  ADD_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [
                    ...state.todos,
                    {
                        id: action.id,
                        text: action.text,
                        completed: false,
                        subtodo:[]
                    }
                ]
            };
        case ADD_SUB_TODO:
            console.log("REDUCER")
            console.log(...state.todos)
            return {
                ...state,
        // THIS LINE DOES'NT WORK :
                ...state.todos[0].subtodo: [ ...state.todos[0].subtodo, {
                    id: action.id,
                    text: action.text
                }]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
    allTodo
})
```

this line is not working :

```
...state.todos[0].subtodo: [ ...state.todos[0].subtodo, {
                        id: action.id,
                        text: action.text
                    }]
```

this is my sub todo object :

```
{
 id: action.id,
 text: action.text
}
```

Comment: how do you expect `state.todos[0].subtodo` to always be the correct location for the subtodo ? Is it only possible to add a subtodo to the first todo ?

Comment: I put a 0 for my test I will put an ID of the parent to-do after when I will resolve this problem,  subtodo is a lost of subtodo created when a todo is create see the case ADD_TODO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that action.parent contains the index of parent todo, try this.

```
        case ADD_SUB_TODO:
            let subtodo = {id: action.id, text: action.text}
            let subtodos = [...state.todos[action.parent].subtodo, subtodo]
            let todo = _.assign({}, state.todos[action.parent], {subtodo: subtodos})
            return _.assign({}, state, {todos: [...state.todos, todo]})
```

if you want to try this with one todo the way you have in your question,

```
        case ADD_SUB_TODO:
            let subtodo = {id: action.id, text: action.text}
            let todo = _.assign({}. state.todos[0], {subtodo: [subtodo]})
            return _.assign({}, state, {todos: [...state.todos, todo]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it was not exactly that but With it I solved the problem :)

Comment: I am curious, what was the actual problem?

Comment: I post my solution as an answer, you can see it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mad Wombat, this is the final code :

```
case ADD_SUB_TODO:

                let subtodo = {id: action.id, text: action.text}
                let subtodoList = _.concat(...state.todos[action.parentId].subtodo, subtodo)
                let todo = _.assign({}, state.todos[action.parentId], {subtodo: subtodoList})

                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...state.todos[action.parentId] = todo,
                    todos: [
                        ...state.todos
                    ]
                };
```

Comment: This looks weird in a few places, but if it works for you, all is good